# How to read data in Qliksense from Databricks Rest API

Tags: rest, pyspark, databricks, qliksense

I am trying to read datasets stored in Databricks DBFS. I want to read these datasets in Qliksense.
I am using Databricks Rest API and getting data in JSON format and also my retrieved data is base64 encoded.
How can get this data in tabular format directly from Rest API.